# How does one compute quotients of $\Bbb Z$-modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modules

Doing homology computations inevitably involves computing quotients of $\Bbb Z$-modules, and I am not familiar with any way of doing this.

Some examples I have been working with are:
$$\frac{\Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z \oplus \Bbb Z}{\langle (2,1,0)\rangle} \text{ and } \frac{\Bbb Z_2 \oplus \Bbb Z}{\langle (1,2) \rangle}.$$

I think in the first case the quotient is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z$.  In the second case I cannot tell.  Would anyone know how to solve problems like this in general?

Comment: This is recurrent question on M.SE and you can find the answer in many places. For the general technique using the [Smith Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) see e.g. [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/690209/classify-mathbbz-5-times-mathbbz-4-times-mathbbz-8-langle1-1-1?rq=1) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765770/classifying-mathbbz-12-times-mathbbz-3-times-mathbbz-6-langle8-2?rq=1).

Comment: Awesome, thanks @user26857, that's exactly what I need. And Maple has a command for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case, you can notice that $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ has a basis (linearly independent spanning set) of $\{(2,1,0), (1,1,0), (0,0,1)\}$. Then taking your quotient is just reducing the size of the basis by 1, so the result is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ as you said.

For the second case, you can think of $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}$ as
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}}{\langle (2,0) \rangle}$$
so your given quotient is 
$$\frac{\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}}{\langle (2,0), (1,2) \rangle}$$
Here, $\{(1,1), (1,2)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, so to calculate the quotient, first eliminate the second basis element. Now expressed in terms of the new basis, $(2,0) = 4(1,1) - 2(1,2)$ so the quotient is
$$\frac{\langle (1,1) \rangle}{4\langle (1,1) \rangle} \cong \mathbb{Z}_4$$

Comment: I think its just a typo.  Should be $(1,2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the help Adam.  I see how to apply this trick in general now.  Play around with the bases until we get something explicit.

Comment: One other thing to take away from this is that "playing around with the bases" can be done in a regular fashion, using row and/or column reduction of matrices.